# I ran `git merge` and got this screen: what editor is this

Tags: git, merge, branch, git-bash

[image]

I tried to merge some changes from my branch to the main, but everytime that I make git merge Diego2, gitbash send this screen IDK what to do

Comment: Did you try doing what it tells you? Enter a commit message?

Comment: yep, but IDK how this works I tried to write something and then press enter but nothings happened\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an vi editor window. This is happening because git cannot perform a fast forward and is prompting you for a message for a merge commit. Vi has a bit of a learning curve and can be confusing for new users.

First, I'd like to mention that you can change what this editor is via the core.editor gitconfig setting. I've included the docs for that below, which describe how to change the editor to emacs (another text editor):

> core.editor
> By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor via one of the shell environment variables VISUAL or EDITOR, or else falls back to the vi editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something else, you can use the core.editor setting:
>
> git config --global core.editor emacs

You can find a list of editor configs [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Appendix-C:-Git-Commands-Setup-and-Config). For other editors, you might have to do some tinkering or googling.

Secondly, I'd like to provide the basics on how to use vi and how commit messages are formatted. Regarding commit messages, the first line is the subject line. An optional body can be added to provide greater detail. It is below the subject line and is separated from it via a blank line.

Vi consists of several, but primarily three modes, NORMAL, INSERT and VISUAL. When first opening vi, you're in NORMAL mode, which is primarily used for navigation. You can begin typing once you enter INSERT mode, and you can select text to be cut or copied in VISUAL mode. Here are some key keybindings:

- `i` enters INSERT mode at the current position
- `Esc` lets you return to NORMAL mode from INSERT/VISUAL mode
- `h` lets you move left in NORMAL mode
- `j` lets you move down in NORMAL mode
- `k` lets you move up in NORMAL mode
- `l` lets you move right in NORMAL mode
- `u` lets you undo changes while in NORMAL mode
- `C-r` / `Ctrl r` lets you redo changes while in NORMAL mode
- `:wq` while in NORMAL mode will write and quit the editor. Doing this allows you to continue with the merge, once you're satisfied with the message.
- `:cq` while in NORMAL mode will quit vim and throw a compiler error. I find this useful if I want to inspect an interactive rebase without actually doing it. **NOTE:** if you do this while merging you'll end up in the `MERGING` git state. You'd have to use `git merge --continue` to continue the merge or `git merge --abort` to abort the merge.

EDIT:
The format of a commit message is:

```
Subject line 

body text
```

Here's a commit message example as well:

```
    Merge branch 'jc/revert-show-parent-info'

    * jc/revert-show-parent-info:
      revert: config documentation fixes
```

In this example, the line beginning with `Merge branch` is the subject line and the line beginning with the asterisk is the start of the body.

For the window you posted, the subject would be: `Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/Diego2'` and it will not contain a body. This is perfectly fine unless you want to add more detail about what's introduced by the merge. If you're satisfied with the current message, press `Esc` to ensure you're in NORMAL mode followed by `:wq` to save and quit vi.

Comment: Thank you so much, for the information, what format the message needs to have?

Comment: @carloszamora I edited my answer to hopefully better explain the formatting.

Comment: i use this git config --global core.editor emacs

Comment: but now I have some torubles bec ause of that, how can I revert this change?

Comment: You probably don't have emacs installed. I was posting that as an example so you can change the editor to something you prefer. To revert it back to the default (i.e. whatever your system default editor is)  or git's default (vi) it's 

`git config --unset --global core.editor`.